# Pass variables in ruby block

Tags: ruby, lambda, scope, closures

Simple code, don't know how to make it work:

```
def foo(&block)
  bar = 0
  block.call
end

foo do
  puts bar
end
```

how to manage block to use `bar` variable from `foo` method scope?

I'm trying implementing DSL, one of it's features is to define how to parse data from `IO` and turn it into `Request` variable.

So I want to create such file:

```
class FooParser < AbstractParser
  read_from_io do
    request = io.readline
  end
end
```

to define, how directly read_from_io should work.

So I think, my AbstractParser should be like this:

```
class AbstractParser
  def initialize
    @io = IO.new
    @request = ""
  end

  def read_from_io(&block)
    @io_reader = block
  end

  ....

  def read
    io = @io
    request = @request
    #here i want to pass io and request to block
    @io_reader.call
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not going to work. You call `read_from_io` from within `FooParser`, but the method is not a class method. I'm not sure if a DSL is the right tool for the job. It looks overly complicated. You could simply implement `read_from_io` as a method in `FooParser` - i.e. `def read_from_io(io)` - and call it from within `AbstractParser`'s `read` method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass it into a block:

```
def foo
  bar = 0
  yield bar
end

foo do |bar|
  puts bar
end
```

Or, if you really need to treat your block as `Proc`:

```
def foo(&block)
  bar = 0
  block.call bar
end
```

Comment: Well, i'm trying to implement DSL, so i want to write piece of code which already have predefined variables, something like this:
read_from_port { request = io.readline }.
So, i think that read_from_port should be like this:
def read_from_port(&block); io = @io; request = @request; block.call; end #here to pass io and request to block

Comment: @Virviil could you edit your question with this additional information? The code put in comments is quite unreadable.

Comment: added explanation to question